# I'm getting this error in python related to randint() and randrange()

Tags: python, valueerror

My code is supposed to create a random string, an array filled with random numbers and a string, and a random integer.
Here's my code:

```
from random import randint, randrange
x = randint(1, randrange(1, 200))
f = [randint(1, randrange(1, 200)), randint(1, randrange(1, 200)), randint(1, randrange(1, 200)), str(randint(1, randrange(1, 200)))]
b = 5
```

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    f = [randint(1, randrange(1, 10)), randint(1, randrange(1, 56)), randint(1, randrange(1, 7)), str(randint(150, randrange(1, 200)))]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/random.py", line 221, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/random.py", line 199, in randrange
    raise ValueError("empty range for randrange() (%d,%d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width))
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (150,39, -111)
```

Answer (score 2):

`str(randint(150, randrange(1, 200)))` can specify an empty range.

`ValueError: empty range for randrange() (150,39, -111)` 150 > 39, which makes it an empty range, as your starting value is higher than your stopping value.

If you had a valid range in `randrange()` such as `randint(150, randrange(150, 200))`

You would get a correct response: `151`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#functions-for-integers

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I went to the link you sent. I understand the problem, thanks for the help.  What I need to accomplish can be done using the method you proposed. Thanks.